# Type Cast UIView Warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, casting

I keep getting a warning that the UIView may not respond to selectedSegmentIndex.  I tried type casting, but I could not get rid of the warning.  I'm assuming I did the cast incorrectly.

What is the proper way to type cast this, to avoid the warning?

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged:(id)sender
{    
    switch ([[[[self.view viewWithTag:100] viewWithTag:202] viewWithTag:203] selectedSegmentIndex]) {

        case 0:
            // code here
            break;
        case 1:
            // code here
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that looks painfully unmaintainable...

Comment: @Paul.s I had to create a bunch of elements manually.  I do use #defines to make the code easier to read.  Would you suggest a better way?

Comment: You know you need a handle to the picker so why not make it an ivar? I'm not fond of `viewWithTag:` and nesting it just seems nasty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
switch ([ (UISegmentedControl*)[[[self.view viewWithTag:100] viewWithTag:202] viewWithTag:203] selectedSegmentIndex]) {
...
```